# Indexing many JSON objects into Elasticsearch - the canonical way

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, jq

Here's a scenario I keep facing, and I am in doubt whether the solution I take is the canonical/smart one. Assume you a file where each line is a valid JSON. Furthermore, each object contains a field `type` and `id` and the pairs of are unique. My goal is to index all the objects into an index on an ES cluster. So far I took two approaches:

Using the `bulk` API together with `jq` using something like:

```
$ cat foo.json | jq -c '. | {"index": {"_index": "your_test_index", "_type": "doc_type"}}, .' | curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @-
```

This works very nicely, but it is super slow.

I tried also to use the Python client, but still I have to read line by line and index them one by one.

Is there some way to "push" the complete file and direct ES to process all lines the same way? Or in other words, what is the efficient way to index LARGE amount of JSON objects in a batch processing fashion?

Comment: Can you define "large"? How many lines/docs do you have and how big is each document?

Comment: For example: 20-30M documents and total of 6-10GB

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the `bulk` approach. But you need to put a bit more work into this, as it's not as easy as creating one file, sending it to ES and expect it to deal with it.

If the file is too big, of course it will struggle.
Do please read this section of the documentation, especially the last part where it describes how you'd need to decide how large a bulk batch needs to be: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html

Each cluster has its own characteristics and each can deal with a certain number of batches/certain number of concurrent batches even. It depends on your specifics, so do please test this and determine the best number for your particular use case.

Comment: Good points, Andrei, plus @Dror will need to [experiment with different bulk sizes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_using_and_sizing_bulk_requests) and see empirically which ones fits best for his document set.

Comment: Of course. There is no auto-magic solution to this. Some experimentation is always recommended.

Comment: Isn't this approach processing the given file line-by-line and "manually" directing the API what to do with each line? Isn't there a way to tell ES to handle all the lines in the same way?

Comment: No, the idea is that you need to split that file into smaller ones. How small those files are is a trial&error approach. And if you have smaller files, you could try and index the files in parallel, something that with one file is not possible and you are under-utilizing Elasticsearch's resources.